# Upgrade FeathersJS CLI problems

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I am trying to upgrade feathers CLI and this is what happens:

`$ feathers -V
2.3.7
$ npm uninstall feathers-cli -g
up to date in 0.137s
$ npm install @feathersjs/cli -g
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
/Users/rv/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/feathers -> /Users/rv/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/@feathersjs/cli/bin/feathers.js
+ @feathersjs/cli@3.6.1
updated 1 package in 16.281s
$ feathers -V
2.3.7`

Has anyone faced such problem and how it could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Appears it was a problem in npm. Installing old version and when uninstalling helped.

P.S. don't forget to reopen terminal